# Validating external recipient before email is sent

Tags: vba, outlook

I am looking for a macro that runs when a user tries to send an email to an external domain (To, Cc, Bcc). It should bring up a userform where the user needs to enter the domain name(s) separated by a comma or semicolon for all the different recipients. If all the domains match the email should be sent else the user should receive a prompt.

I found code and tried making changes.

```
Public pass As Integer

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Dim prompt As String
Dim strMsg As String
Dim Address As String
Dim lLen
Dim a As String

Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

Set recips = Item.Recipients
For Each recip In recips
    Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor

    Address = LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS))
    lLen = Len(Address) - InStrRev(Address, "@")

    Select Case Right(Address, lLen)
    Case "abc.com", "abd.com" ', "efg.com"
     
    Case Else ' remove case else line to be warned when sending to the addresses
        strMsg = strMsg & " " & Address & vbNewLine
    End Select
Next

If strMsg <> "" Then
    prompt = "This email will be sent outside of the company to:" & vbNewLine & strMsg & vbNewLine & "Please check recipient address." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Do you still wish to send?"

   'MsgBox "You are sending email to external user(s) " & vbNewLine & "Please ask your lead for validation", vbInformation, "External User!"

    UserForm3.Show

    If UserForm3.Cancelled Then
        Cancel = True
    Else
        Cancel = False
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Code for User form:

```
Private IsCancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
Cancelled = IsCancelled
End Property

Private Sub Image5_Click()
If TextBox1.Value = "123456789" Then
    MsgBox "Validation Successful!", vbInformation, "Success!"
    Unload Me
    Cancel = False
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid Login details", vbCritical, "Invalid"
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
OnCancel
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
    Cancel = True
    OnCancel
End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnCancel()
IsCancelled = True

Unload Me
Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: It is unclear why you want user input. You can get the domains yourself. This will be a major annoyance to users. As well anything with user-input will be unreliable due to mistakes or malice.

Comment: Thanks, niton! I need the user to manually enter the domain so that if they have added any recipient incorrectly (may be typos).  For example: the user has to send email to **test@abc.com** but mistakenly typed **test@abcd.com**. So the user will type "abc" but it will not match with the domain from the recipient filed and the user should not be able to send the email.

Comment: Would the mail be sent if the user types "abcd" in the userform?

Comment: yes, that correct!

Answer (score 0):

Re:  For example: the user has to send email to test@abc.com but mistakenly typed test@abcd.com. So the user will type "abc" but it will not match with the domain from the recipient filed and the user should not be able to send the email.

Would the mail be sent if the user types "abcd" in the userform?

yes, that correct!

---

If you accept whatever the user enters in a userform, then version 1.
If the user should be treated in the normal way, then version 2.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim recips As Recipients
Dim recip As Recipient
Dim pa As propertyAccessor
Dim prompt As String
Dim strMsg As String
Dim Address As String
Dim lLen As Long

Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

Set recips = Item.Recipients

For Each recip In recips

    Set pa = recip.propertyAccessor
    
    Address = LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS))
    lLen = Len(Address) - InStrRev(Address, "@")
        
    Select Case Right(Address, lLen)
    
    Case "abc.com", "abd.com" ', "efg.com"
         
    Case Else
        strMsg = strMsg & " " & Address & vbNewLine
    End Select

Next


' version 1 - give the user control
If strMsg <> "" Then
    
    prompt = "This email will be sent outside of the company to" & vbNewLine
    prompt = prompt & " recipient(s) with domain that is not approved:" & vbNewLine & strMsg
    prompt = prompt & vbNewLine & "Please check recipient address(es)."
    
    prompt = prompt & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Do you still wish to send?"
    
    If MsgBox(prompt, vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Domain not listed!") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
    
End If


' version 2 - strictly forbidden if not on list
If strMsg <> "" Then

    Cancel = True
        
    prompt = "This email has recipient(s) with a domain that is not approved:" & vbNewLine & strMsg
    prompt = prompt & vbNewLine & "Please change recipient address(es)."
    
    prompt = prompt & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Send cancelled."
    
    MsgBox prompt, vbCritical, "Domain not approved!"
    
End If

End Sub
```